# Xcode10 - Timer triggers function repeatedly

Tags: timer, xcode10

The Timer should start a function each second. I wrote this, assuming that the timer is started when the program  gets started. Where is the error?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTimer.invalidate()

        myTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(startAnimation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



    }
    @objc func startAnimation(){
        print("Started")  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a timer. But you never started it going (also called scheduling the timer). So nothing happens.

If you wanted to create and start the timer in one move, you should have called https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer

Comment: But not in the method you used. So that would be a different question. Have you considered looking at the documentation?

Comment: Please stop asking new questions as comments. If you have another question ask a new QUESTION